# I am helping develop a SMS/MMS messaging app for android but we cant send mms from Sprint and Verizon?

Tags: android, messaging, mms

Is there some secret sauce to third party sms/mms messaging apps? Our app downloads and Installs fine, sends sms fine, receives sms fine.  The app also receives mms fine, but when trying to send MMS from either a Sprint or Verizon phone message always fails (quickly).  We have tried many different APNs but I am beginning to think that maybe these APNs are only for GSM and not CDMA networks?  Sprint does not allow editing to apns so I cant find APN settings except on one phone.  Here is the most recent APN info I have:

Sprint APN
-Name: cinet.spcs
-Proxy: not set
-Port: not set
-Username: null
-Password:****
-MMSC: http://mms.sprintpcs.com
-MMS proxy: 68.28.31.7
-MMS port: 80
-MCC: 310
-MNC: 120
-Authentication Type:none
-APN type: default,mms
-APN protocol: IPv4
-APN roaming: IPv4

Verizon APN
-Name: Verizon Internet
-APN: VZWINTERNET
-Proxy: Not set
-Port: Not set
-Username: Not set
-Password: Not set
-Server: Not set
-MMSC: Not set
-Multimedia messaging proxy: Not set
-Multimedia messaging port: Not set
-MCC: 311
-MNC: 480
-Authentication type: Not set
-APN type: default,dun,supl
-APN protocol: IPv4/IPv6
-APN roaming protocol: IPv4/IPv6

T-Mobile and At&t work well but cannot get MMS to send from Sprint & Verizon phones once app is installed??

Comment: Do you get any output on your stack trace while sending?

Comment: I believe we have the correct apn and MMSC number it must be something else.  Still have no idea.

Comment: Try reproducing the error by sending an MMS from Spring or Verizon networks and post the output from the stack trace. Did you try that? Do you get any errors/output on the operation performed?

Comment: [1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.767-0800: httpConnection: params list
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.774-0800:  token  = 5351
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.777-0800:  url  = http://mmsc.vmobl.com:8088
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.779-0800:  method  = POST
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.781-0800:  isProxySet = true
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.784-0800:  proxyHost = 68.28.31.2
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.787-0800:  proxyPort = 80
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:22.791-0800: [HttpUtils] createHttpClient w/ socket timeout 60000 ms, , UA=Android-Mms/2.0
[1.0.6] 150303 01:04:26.257-0800: Failed to send offline mmsmessage: mid=4, status=225‏

Comment: wow i didn't think that would translate over to a huge block it was a list.  Error code 225

http://www.simplydroid.com/forum/getting-error-mms-error-225-insufficient-fund-when-trying-send-pictures-10288.html

Comment: wow i didn't think that would translate over to a huge block it was a list.  

Error code 225

http://www.simplydroid.com/forum/getting-error-mms-error-225-insufficient-fund-when-trying-send-pictures-10288.html

The phones I am testing on are Prepaid Sprint LG Tibute and Verizon LG Transpre.  Sprint has 1gb of data, Verizon has .5G (half) of data.  

I am getting reception 

Tested Wifi OFF and ON

We have the correct Message Center Numer

I don't understand what format i am missing it works on GSM fine

Comment: `Failed to send offline mms` do you have an active internet connection when you try to send MMS?

Comment: I think it may be a problem with either carriers or certain phones or a combination of the two restricting access to Get apn requests.  Or getting only the defualt and not the mms apn if they are different.   For instance some times the Type of apn will read Type: "defualt,mms,supl,hipri" this means all uses share the same apn, but if mms is not the same apn as default perhaps Get is not retrieving the correct apn.  Just a theory I still have no idea.