# Verizon & Sprint MMS issue sending on Android

Tags: android, mms, instant-messaging

I am building third party Android messaging app to send & receive mms(image and text) over all type of provider(T-Mobile, China Telecom, AT&T, Verizon, Sprint etc)

The messaging app is failed to send mms from devices with Verizon and Sprint provider.

But it can receive any mms from any provider(T-Mobile, China Telecom, AT&T)

I am sure APN information is correct. It is same as APN Settings from chompSMS app(chompSMS app > Settings menu item > SMS & MMS Settings > MMS Settings).

Here is APN Settings for Sprint:

- MMSC: http://mmsc.vmobl.com:8088
- MMS Proxy: 68.28.31.2
- MMSPort: 80

Here is APN Settings for Verizon

- MMSC: http://mms.vtext.com/servlets/mms
- MMS Proxy: (empty)
- MMSPort: (empty)

I am not sure what's wrong  :(

Any help would be nice  :)

Comment: It seems you're not the only one having that problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763514/i-am-helping-develop-a-sms-mms-messaging-app-for-android-but-we-cant-send-mms-fr